# Assign appropriate variables so that these declarations are correct

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I was given a following code:

```
int TAB[4][6];
int (*FF(int k))[3];
char *NAP[]={"nap1", "nap2", "nap3"};
double T[][2]={{1.0,1.0},{0.},{2.0,3.0}};
```

and I'm supposed to make these declarations correct (so that they don't return any errors in a compiler):

```
a = &T;
b = FF;
c = FF(9);
d = TAB[2];
e = FF(9)[1];
f = *NAP+1;
g = *NAP[1]++;
```

I only managed to do few. My compiler (xCode) didn't return any errors for these, but I have no idea how to declare the remaining 3...

What I managed to do:

```
1.int (*c)[3]= FF(9); 
2.int *d = TAB[2];
3.char *f = *NAP+1;
4.char g = *NAP[1]++;
```

1. The `FF` function returns a pointer to a 3-element array, so we need a pointer to 3-element array?
2. Since `TAB[2]` is a second subarray then just a pointer is enough ?
3. `*NAP+1` is pointing to the address of the `"a"` character of the first word in the array `NAP` so we need a pointer to store that address?
4. This time `*NAP[1]++` is actually pointing to a value so just a variable will do the job?

Comment: use the `cdecl` program

Comment: use `auto` from c++11 xD

Comment: @Take_Care_: The question is tagged C, not C++! And that is hardly the lesson.

Comment: We are not a "do my homework" service.

Comment: I know you're not, hence why I'm only posting those that i struggle with. You don't have to help if you don't want to. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I show how you solve these annoying declaration puzzles like a professional: **cheat**. Use the `cdecl` program, which can be found as a [service](https://cdecl.org/) too.

For example:

```
cdecl> explain double T[][2];
declare T as array of array 2 of double
```

Thus, the declaration `double T[][2];` declares `T` as *array of array 2 of double*. If you use `&` to take an *address of something*, the type of that address is *pointer to something*. Thus since the value of `&T` is assigned to `a`, `a` should be declared as a ***pointer to*** array of array 2 of double:

```
cdecl> declare a as pointer to array of array 2 of double;
double (*a)[][2]
```

---

Likewise for `FF`:

```
cdecl> explain int (*FF(int))[3];
declare FF as function (int) returning pointer to array 3 of int
```

so `FF` is a function. Now, to have a *variable* where it could be assigned. The name of a function decays to a *pointer* to the function - so here we need to use a *pointer* to function:

```
cdecl> declare b as pointer to function (int) returning pointer to array 3 of int
int (*(*b)(int ))[3]
```

---

For `c`, since `FF` is a *function (int) returing pointer to array 3 of int*, if you call `FF` with an `int` (9)  as the argument, it returns a *pointer to array 3 of int*:

```
cdecl> declare c as pointer to array 3 of int
int (*c)[3]
```

And for `e` we dereference the pointer with the indexing operator, so we get an lvalue of type *array of 3 int*. One *cannot* assign arrays to variables, but array lvalues decay into pointers to the *first* element, so an *array of 3 int* decays into a *pointer to int*. Well, you know for sure how to declare a pointer to int, but I am lazy and want to do no mistake, so I just paste stuff into `cdecl`:

```
cdecl> declare e as pointer to int;
int *e;
```

---

Thus finally we get:

```
int TAB[4][6];
int (*FF(int k))[3];
char *NAP[]={"nap1", "nap2", "nap3"};
double T[][2]={{1.0,1.0},{0.},{2.0,3.0}};

int main(void) {
    double (*a)[][2];
    int (*(*b)(int ))[3];
    int (*c)[3];
    int *d;
    int *e;
    char *f;
    char g;

    a = &T;
    b = FF;
    c = FF(9);
    d = TAB[2];
    e = FF(9)[1];
    f = *NAP+1;
    g = *NAP[1]++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You've helped me a lot! That website is awesome, however I have no idea how did you make it show you the specific proplem output. What should I input for it to solve a problem like this: int TAB[4][6], d=TAB[2]?

Comment: well, it doesn't directly in *all* cases, but if `int TAB[4][6]` is an *array 4 of array 6 of int* (use `explain int TAB[4][6]` as the command), then naturally indexing the first array, the *array 4*, you get *array 6 of int* - and arrays decays to pointers to the first element, so that will decay to *pointer to int*, thus that's what you want to give to the service: `declare d as pointer to int`. cdecl is very handy when you need to make sense of complicated declarations or produce them.

Comment: The first appendix from K&R is very useful to learn to interpret precedence in type declarators, I'm having fun reading it :) Nevertheless  +1 for the `cdecl` tool.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thank you for the thorough explanation! I've read the precedence rules few times already but it still get's very confusing. I think I'll print it out and just stick to my laptop or something :)

Comment: I strongly disagree. A professional knows which types he needs, so he does the declarations himself. A good C programmer does not write overly complex declarators, but uses intermediate aliases to make the code more readable (and because those `typedef`ed names are needed anyway). There very rarely (if ever) is need for `cdecl` once one has understood the C syntax. Said that: `cdecl` has its uses to work through bad code, e.g. for maintenance work.

Comment: @Olaf I wouldn't even try to decipher `int (*FF(int k))[3];` because I might get it wrong. At first as I glimpsed at it, I thought it was a pointer to a function. One should spend one's limited brain capacity onto things that matter. If a tool can do the thing for me faster, then I use the tool, and spend my brain capacity for something else. Naturally, I'd personally never use cdecl to write definitions for *my* code.

Comment: @Olaf, ofc this is gibberish but these r stuff I revise before my exam. I can't imagine having to use cdecl in the future at work for example. I'd rather use declarations I know and imprement it in a clear way.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The more brain capacity you "off-load" to computers, the less brain capacity one has. The brain is more like muscles in that aspect: if degrades if you don't train it. (there are a lot of studies about that - more modern show the smartphone-effect). Such stuff is a good training. But my point actually was: a good programmer will not use such complex declarator syntax. And don't worry: we will never exhaust our brain-capacity.

Comment: @Mike.e87: As I wrote: such tasks are a good training. A lot of stuff you learn at school won't be used lateron, but it is the meta-knowledge which is trained by such things. If you don't have such stuff as homework permanemtly, I'd recommend to read about the "spiral rule" and figure out yourself. Only if you want to really lean, of course. It will eventually pop up once in a time in your job and you don't always have cdecl available.